Cómo pegar texto enriquecido desde el portapapeles en Python
soy bastante novato en Python.
Estoy intentando crear un pequeño programa que pueda copiar y pegar texto enriquecido (negrita, cursiva, etc...) desde el portapapeles a mi aplicación.
(OS: Windows 11) (Python versión: 3.12)
He instalado el paquete pyclip (versión actual 0.7.0) que según la documentación del paquete soporta tanto datos de texto como binarios desde el portapapeles.
He escrito este código de prueba siguiendo las indicaciones de la documentación de pyclip:
import pyclip

texto = pyclip.paste()
print(texto)

pyclip.clear()

Cuando copio el siguiente texto desde mi correo electrónico:

"Esto es un texto en negrita en mi correo electrónico.'

El resultado en pantalla del script es el correcto:

b'Esto es un\xc2\xa0texto en negrita\xc2\xa0en mi correo electr\xc3\xb3nico.'

Sin embargo, si copio un texto similar desde un documento de Microsoft Word:

"Esto es un texto en negrita en un documento de Word."

El resultado en pantalla no es el correcto, no aparece la codificación:

b'Esto es un texto en negrita en un documento de Word.'

Entiendo que será porque Word no usa negrita con codificación 'utf-8', pero:
¿Cómo puedo recuperar la información de texto en negrita del portapapeles?
Obviamente está ahí porque si pego este mismo texto en cualquier otro programa, por ejemplo, el de mi correo electrónico (que no es de Microsoft) el texto en negrita aparece perfectamente.
Supongo que tendré que acceder directamente a la API de Windows, pero desconozco cómo hacerlo.
Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

No se si pueda ayudar mucho, dado que no pago microsoft 365. Sin embargo, he podido replicar el fallo usando Libre Office Writer.
No reconozco la causa, y mis pruebas mostraron el mismo fallo también en los modulos pyperclip y jaraco.clipboard. No he probado modulos más alla de la primera pagina de busqueda de Google con las palabras "clipboard python".

Probé algo overkill, pero util. Si usamos el modulo de gui PySide2 o, presumiblemente, cualquier otro binding de Qt. Podemos hacer el siguiente código:
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

# Para evitar que el garbage collector elimine los pyobject que envuelven a los objetos de Qt, guardamos estos en variables globales.
app = QApplication([])
clipboard = app.clipboard()

print(clipboard.mimeData().html())

No te preocupes, no se abrirá ninguna ventana con este código solo.
Esto, nos devuelve un html que vi que refleja con presición (al menos en la etiqueta body) el formato.
clipboard.mimeData() nos devuelve un objeto QMimeData que podemos convertir a texto, html, etc.
A continuación, un ejemplo con el texto "40a"
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="generator" content="LibreOffice 7.2.1.2 (Windows)"/>
    <style type="text/css">
            @page { size: 21cm 29.7cm; margin: 2cm }
            p { line-height: 115%; margin-bottom: 0.25cm; background: transparent }
    </style>
</head>
<body lang="es-AR" link="#000080" vlink="#800000" dir="ltr"><p style="line-height: 100%; margin-bottom: 0cm; text-decoration: none">
    <b>40</b><span style="font-weight: normal">a</span></p>
</body>
</html>

Probablemente, esto te sirva para comenzar, quizá requieras aprenderte html y css.
Hipotesis El clipboard podría trabajar con un formato estandar llamado Mime o Mime Data, el cual no es del todo compatible con los modulos promedio de clipboard de Python. Eso explicaría también por que se puede copiar contenido de Word en un servicio de mail no relacionado con Microsoft.

Muchas gracias Dante S.

Sí que me ha funcionado. De hecho me estoy planteando cambiar la GUI de mi pequeño programa (he usado Tkinter) a PySide/Qt ya que lo he instalado. El problema es que ahora tengo que aprender Qt :)

@Gaspar A mi me gustan los bindings de Qt, me parece una librería de GUI mucho más avanzada y completa que Tkinter, aunque un poco más dificil de aprender. Si se te complica mucho aprenderlo, sea por falta de tiempo o lo que sea, siempre tenés la alternativa (aunque menos optimizada) de usar PySide solamente para acceder al clipboard y Tkinter para el resto.
